# Any available solution for Mac Air : ssh githup operation timed out?

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I've searched and tried kinds of solution before I ask this question, but obviously it doesn't work. That may be a common problem of Mac Air:

And the problem is that when I tried to establish new repo for git and type:

```
git remote add origin https://githup.com/username/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```

I got this error:

```
fatal : unable to access 'https://githup.com/....': failed to connect to githup.com443; Operation timed out.
```

If I use git like this:

```
git remote add origin git@githup.com:username/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

I got these:

```
ssh: connect to host githup.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I just begin to doubt that `ssh` service of Mac Air may be not available.

Any useful solution ?

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com instead of https://githup.com.
I guess that is the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed it already. Anyway, thanks very much and really sorry for asking question before checking stupid type error like this.